# Flutter error - failed assertion: line 213 pos 15: 'data != null': is not true at the time of fetching data from firestore

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Working on Android app using flutter. Trying to fetch documents from firestore & show on the screen through a widget. Here is my code...

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget userTimeline = new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
                child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tripsDocs').snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');

                    new ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        new ListTile(
                          title: document['docTitle'] != null? new Text(document['docTitle']) : new Text("Hello"),
                          subtitle: new Text('Suresh'),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ));

    return new Scaffold(

      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          userTimeline,
        ],
      ),

    );

  }
}
```

But, whenever I'm executing this widget I'm getting following error...

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 213 pos 15: 'data != null': is not true
```

Can't able to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure "document['docTitle']" is not null? If it's null, the Text could throw that exception

Comment: It could be ```null``` also. In that case, can't I do something like this ```title: new Text(document['docTitle'] ?? 'Hello')``` ?

Comment: title: new Text(document['docTitle'] ?? 'Hello'). This is not correct, please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the constructor of Text

```dart
const Text(this.data, {
    Key key,
    this.style,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.softWrap,
    this.overflow,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.maxLines,
  }) : assert(data != null),
       textSpan = null,
       super(key: key);
```

With

> final String data;

As you can see, data is a required field and it must be not null.

You can use below code in case your data could be null

```dart
title: document['docTitle'] != null? new Text(document['docTitle']) : new Text("Hello"),
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting this error... ```A build function returned null. The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>. Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".```

Comment: Shall I need to prepend ```return``` with ```new ListView``` & ```new ListTitle``` ?

Comment: It says "A build function return null". How is your build function?

Comment: My build function returning a ```Scaffold``` & I'm calling above widget from my Scaffold.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you are trying to add some null data to Text.
for adding text Content to Text widget dynamically better to setState of text place where you are getting that data. Delay for getting content cause this error. so a condition check for data is also good.

```
@override
  void initState() {
setState(() {
       docText=document['docTitle'];
      });

    super.initState();
  }
```

....

```
title: new Text( docText == null? 'Loading ..',document['docTitle']),
```

try this way

Answer (score 2):

if your data is not null, then run the command on your project terminal `flutter clean`. It may remove your error. I have similar issue.

Comment: This solved a similar error that was flaking for me. Never forget to `flutter clean`!

Comment: This caused my 2.x.x non-null-safe project to turn into a null-safe one. Maybe fvm is related. I had to restart Visual Studio Code and null-safety is gone again.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the returned form of the snapshot you get is json that matches what was read. If the return from the snapshot is in the form of an array [] then it must match, if it is an array object [{ }] then it must also match

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

change the name of the collection in the cloud firestore and in each query you have in the project.

that will change the name on the firebase page, at least that solved my problem

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection("colection").snapshots(),
```

to

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots(),
```